# Generating .asc tiles that represent heights on a map

Tags: qgis

I'm new to QGIS and following the next tutorial (see link), as I'd like to 3D print landscapes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1QD0ukdUzU

I'm able to follow in making the grid, but then the tutor starts importing .asc files that are the heights of the map (grey shaded/ min 1.09). This is where I got stuck. How did he/she generate those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The video you link to is using OS Terrain 50 digital elevation data. It is a free download available from the Ordnance Survey: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/terrain-50.html

click on Free Download and then scroll down to the relevant entry (see screenshot). Make sure you select ASCII Grid from the dropdown and then go through the download process.

[image: OS Terrain 50 entry on OpenData portal]

OS Terrain 50 is a fairly low resolution terrain dataset (50m horizontal resolution). If you're printing smaller areas that need a greater resolution the Environment Agency also hosts LiDAR data of much higher resolution which can be downloaded in .asc format here: https://environment.data.gov.uk/ds/survey/#/survey

Comment: Thank you! 
Both for OS and the greater resolution LiDAR data.

Comment: @Amy - if it has answered the question please don't forget to click on the little tick to mark it as answered. thanks.